# Move Thead section as first column

Tags: html, css

Consider the following html

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>data 1.1</td>
        <td>data 1.2</td>
        <td>data 1.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data 2.1</td>
        <td>data 2.2</td>
        <td>data 2.3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

It renders as the following image:

[image]

Is it possible by only using css to have the previous html render like the following image? (please note the indexes)

[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this operation (on any matrix) is genereally called [`transpose`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose). You might find other solutions using that name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have to do this with css and you can't change your `HTML` you can do it with `Flexbox`.

```css
table {
  display: flex;
}
thead tr, tbody tr {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data 1.1</td>
      <td>data 1.2</td>
      <td>data 1.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data 2.1</td>
      <td>data 2.2</td>
      <td>data 2.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Wow That was fast! Will wait a couple of hours to see if there other alternatives out there :)